# Barcode scanner in android from within my app and not via intent but have an inbuilt barcode scanner

Tags: android, barcode

Hi i am a student doing an academy project based on android.my project mainly has to perform a book search from 3 webites like amazon,flipkart,rediff etc using a barcode scaner to scan the barcode and fetch the data of the book from the 3 sites.

i used the zxing library to develop a barcode similar to the existing barcode scanner and ran it on the android emulator and on phone and its working

nw i wana include this barcode scanner inside my bookcomparison app but i dont wana call the app via an intent but i wana have an inbuilt barcode scanner inside my app.

pls help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

See this post:

http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

Sean Owen, one of the developers for ZXing, has also mentioned this on this blog. Do take a look at his comments.